# Nested sets using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-sets

I have been wrestling with this for some time now. I am seeking to run a query against a model using ActiveRecord.

Migration:

```
class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :employees, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string :emp
      t.integer :lft
      t.integer :rgt

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/seeds.rb

```
Employee.delete_all
Employee.create(emp: 'Albert', lft: 1, rgt: 12)
Employee.create(emp: 'Bert', lft: 2, rgt: 3)
Employee.create(emp: 'Chuck', lft: 4, rgt: 11)
Employee.create(emp: 'Donna', lft: 5, rgt: 6)
Employee.create(emp: 'Eddie', lft: 7, rgt: 8)
Employee.create(emp: 'Fred', lft: 9, rgt: 10)
```

The SQL I want to convert to AR is:

```
SELECT COUNT(E2.emp) AS indentation, E1.emp 
FROM Employees AS E1, Employees AS E2 
WHERE E1.lft BETWEEN E2.lft AND E2.rgt 
GROUP BY E1.emp 
ORDER BY E1.lft
```

So far the only way I have been able to get it to work in rails is using the following which returns an array and I am not sure of the significance of "Employee" at the start of the statement.

```
Employee.connection.select_all("SELECT COUNT(P2.emp) AS indentation, P1.emp FROM Employees AS P1, Employees AS P2 WHERE P1.lft BETWEEN P2.lft AND P2.rgt GROUP BY P1.emp ORDER BY P1.lft")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the SQL directly:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(E2.emp) AS indentation, E1.emp FROM Employees AS E1, Employees AS E2 WHERE E1.lft BETWEEN E2.lft AND E2.rgt GROUP BY E1.emp ORDER BY E1.lft"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

which will result in:

```
[{"indentation"=>1, "emp"=>"Albert", 0=>1, 1=>"Albert"},                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 {"indentation"=>2, "emp"=>"Bert", 0=>2, 1=>"Bert"},                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 {"indentation"=>2, "emp"=>"Chuck", 0=>2, 1=>"Chuck"},                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 {"indentation"=>3, "emp"=>"Donna", 0=>3, 1=>"Donna"},                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 {"indentation"=>3, "emp"=>"Eddie", 0=>3, 1=>"Eddie"},                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 {"indentation"=>3, "emp"=>"Fred", 0=>3, 1=>"Fred"}]
```